# Getting error while running same function on loop, no error otherwise

Tags: r

I have written a function to sort of manually perform k means clustering. The function works as intended while calling it, but when same function is called multiple times in loop, it throws error:

> Error in 1:nrow(centers) : argument of length 0

the function is:

```
km = function(df,c=2,times=10){
    # browser()
    df = sapply(df,as.numeric)
    centers = sapply(1:ncol(df), function(x)runif(c, min(df[,x]), max(df[,x])))
    print(1:nrow(centers))
    for (i in seq_len(times)){
        dist_mat = sapply(1:nrow(centers), function(x)as.matrix(dist(rbind(df,centers[x,])))[nrow(df)+1,1:nrow(df)] )
        seed_allot = apply(dist_mat,1,which.max)
        centers = sapply(1:(ncol(df)),function(x) tapply(df[,x],seed_allot,mean))
    }
    # plot(df[,1],df[,2],col=seed_allot)
    # points(centers,pch=14)
}
```

the call which works without errors:

```
km(iris)
```

loop call which throws error:

```
for (i in seq_len(1000)){km(iris)}
```

Comment: The error seems to be random. If you call `km` function few times then you can see an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it can happen with `kmeans` clustering, even when you specify two clusters (or centres), you may get only one cluster (i.e. all the samples are allocated to one cluster, and other has zero sample).

In that case, `seed_allot` becomes all 1's or 2's, and, it makes `centers` (the one comes after `seed_allot`) has only one row.

It makes the class of `centers` to be `numeric` - whereas you are expecting a `matrix`. The `nrow(centers)` returns `NULL` for objects of class `numeric`, and you get the error message.

Error occurs at next iteration at the line of

`dist_mat = sapply(1:nrow(centers), 
               function(x) as.matrix(dist(rbind(df,centers[x,]))) row(df)+1,
                           1:nrow(df)])`.

Comment: sounds reasonable. but as i am alloting centers by taking random between min and max of each feature, i cant think of how this could happen. i will drill down and see exactly for which combination this is happening (by looping through different seeds)

Comment: You could assign centers randomly to different data points - making sure they are not the same. (I think the reason why this happens exactly because the way you are assigning centers)